# how can update tuleap

Tags: updates, tuleap

I can't update tuleap from 8.2 to 8.3
I have next error:

```
http://tuleap.net/pub/tuleap/yum/rhel/5-php53/stable/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTP Error 404: Not Found
Trying other mirror.
Error: Cannot retrieve repository metadata (repomd.xml) for repository: Tuleap. Please verify its path and try again
```

How can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

The yum repository you have configured for Tuleap points to a wrong (probably outdated) URL. In order to fix it, you'd have to update your configuration to match the configuration described in [the installation guide](http://tuleap-documentation.readthedocs.org/en/latest/installation-guide/full-installation.html).

1. Change to the `root` user
2. `cd /etc/yum.repos.d`
3. Look for the file containing the Tuleap URL you specified in your question. It's probably called `Tuleap.repo` or something similar
4. Edit the file's contents to match the configuration in the installation guide:

```
[Tuleap]
name=Tuleap
baseurl=http://ci.tuleap.net/yum/tuleap/rhel/6/dev/$basearch
enabled=1
gpgcheck=0
```

Note that you may have to change the `6` there to `5-php53`, depending on your OS version.

Comment: Can you say me how do I install version 8.3, the system offers me to install version 8.4